# REST Windows Phone Photo upload

Tags: rest, windows-phone-7, multipartform-data, restsharp

I'm trying to upload a photo to a REST api in a Windows Phone 7 application using RestSharp for my Gets/Posts.
The post parameters are as follows:

> **photo**: 
>       The photo, encoded as multipart/form-data
>   **photo_album_id**:
>       Identifier of an existing photo album, which may be an event or group
>   album

I've created my request, but every time I get back `"{\"details\":\"missing photo parameter\",\"problem\":\"The API request is malformed\"}\n`

My photo parameter looks like this:

> "---------------------------8cd9bfbafb3ca00\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"somefile.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n(some binary junk listed here)\r\n-----------------------------8cd9bfbafb3ca00--"

I'm not quite sure if it's a problem with how I'm presenting the binary data for the image (currently in my PhotoTaskCompleted event, I read the contents of e.ChosenPhoto into a byte[] and pass that to a helper method to create the form data) or if I just don't create the form correctly.

I'm just trying to do this a simple as possible, then I can refactor once I know how it all works.

```
 void ImageObtained(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {

        var photo = ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto);
        var form = PostForm(photo);
        var request = new RequestWrapper("photo", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("photo_album_id", _album.album_id);
        request.AddParameter("photo", form);

        request.Client.ExecuteAsync<object>(request, (response) =>
          {
               var s = response.Data;
          });
    }

    private string CreateBoundary()
    {
        return "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

    }

    private string PostForm(byte[] data)
    {
        string boundary = CreateBoundary();
        StringBuilder post = new StringBuilder();
        post.Append(boundary);
        post.Append("\r\n");
        post.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"somefile.jpg\"");
        post.Append("\r\n");
        post.Append("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        post.Append("\r\n\r\n");
        post.Append(ConvertBytesToString(data));
        post.Append("\r\n");
        post.Append("--");
        post.Append(boundary);
        post.Append("--");

        return post.ToString();
    }

    public static string ConvertBytesToString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        string output = String.Empty;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hammock for Windows Phone makes this real simple.
You just add the file to the request using the `AddFile` method and pass it the photo stream.

```
        var request = new RestRequest("photo", WebMethod.Post);
        request.AddParameter("photo_album_id", _album.album_id);
        request.AddFile("photo", filename, e.ChosenPhoto);
```

Comment: RestSharp has request.AddFile() too. But Hammock is a great library as well and I'm glad you solved your problem

Comment: good to know. thanks. Hammock has great oauth support which was a key factor in the switch. I really like restsharp too. Great to have cool libs available.

Answer (score 0):

Hum are you sure that your PostForm is correct ? The content-* params should be set in the headers of your POST and not in the body ?

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,"blabla");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: All the examples I've seen are similar to what you are suggesting, so what has me confused is this photo parameter: photo - The photo, encoded as multipart/form-data. I originally tried just setting the content of the photo parameter to the binary data, but received the same malformed data error.