# foursquare photo checkin in windows phone

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, foursquare

any one know how to use foursquare photo check-in in windows phone?

i have seen below link, but it is not helpful. i have to upload photo

[Foursquare SDK for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460012/foursquare-sdk-for-net)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Foursquare api, it doesn't look like the [check-in](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) event accepts a photo parameter.
You will most likely need to post a check-in, and then [post a photo](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add) and reference the check-in id in that post.

A 3rd party sdk might wrap that up into one call for you if that's what you're looking for, but I'm not familiar with any.

If you're looking at how to add a photo to a post request, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032861/rest-windows-phone-photo-upload/5063071#5063071).